# Exponencial grow, with controlable outcome and steps.

Tags: exponential-function, step-function

I'm not a mathematician so I'm not sure how to calculate what I need. The problem is, I want to go from 0 to 0.9, growing exponentially, over a **determined** amount of steps. And with every step added together, the overall result must be 9. Is there a way to calculate this? thanks

Comment: Please show what have you tried so far.

Comment: There is no real number $x$ such that $\mathrm{e}^x=0$. The closest thing we have is $\lim_{x \to -\infty}{\mathrm{e}^x} = 0$. As such, nothing can grow exponentially from zero.

Comment: @HarishChandraRajpoot I didn't try anything as I realy dont know how to

Comment: @Lemmon thanks for the input. if the first number was 0,04 would it be possible?

Comment: @r_iho I can't say for certain, but it seems like it should be possible then, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Your description of your problem is not clear. If $\ q\ $ is the quantity you want to grow exponentially, do you want it to grow *continuously* or in *discrete* steps.  Your phrase "over a **determined** amount of steps" would seem to *suggest* the latter, but it's certainly not obvious that that's what you mean.

A quantity which grows exponentially in discrete steps will have the form $\ s(1+g)^n\ $ after $\ n\ $ steps, where $\ s\ $ is the initial value of the quantity, and $\ g\ $ is the fraction by which it grows at each step.  If you add all those values together, you'll get
$$
s\sum_{i=1}^n(1+g)^i=s\left(\frac{(1+g)^n-1}{g}\right)\ .
$$
If you start with $\ s=0\ $  this quantity will remain zero no matter how many steps you take, so you could never reach *any* positive value.  If you start with a positive value for $\ s\ $, however, and $\ N\ $ is the "determined" number of steps you have available, then you will need
$$
0.9=s\left(\frac{(1+g)^N-1}{g}\right)\ ,
$$
or, equivalentlty,
$$
(1+g)^N-\left(\frac{0.9}{s}\right)g-1=0\ .
$$
For any fixed $\ N\ $ and $\ s>0\ $, this equation will have a *unique* positive solution for $\ g\ $, and this growth rate will achieve your aim of "going from" $\ s\ $ "to $\ 0.9\ $" in $\ N\ $ steps, *provided* $\ s>0\ $.  In general, there will be no simple formula for the solution, however.  While it will be possible to obtain arbitrarily close numerical approximations to the solution, that's the best you can hope for in the general case.